# How to make a right-click translation dictionary application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to write a dictionay application on C#. There is a scenarios that user selects a text and press a hot-key, I want to pop-up a quick windows that display the search result of the selected word (just like Lingoes does)

How would I do it in C#?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the selection of text happen within your application or do you wish to select within any application and then use a global hot key to pop up a notification sort of like the balloon notifying you when there is a new software update available for Windows?

Comment: "How would I do it in C#?" Do what? get when the hotkey is pressed? pop-up a window? Get the selected text from a winform?

Answer (score 0):

Start with Google this:

- hooks, global hotkeys (for monitoring global keyboard and mouse events)
- WinAPI (to do such tricks as grab any selected text)

Answer (score 0):

I've written program you're talking about. You can check the code here - [IDictionary](https://www.assembla.com/code/idictionary/subversion/nodes).

Regards